# Movie about an alien who overtakes different persons

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie about an alien who overtakes different persons. The FBI tries to hunt him down, but he manages to escape at the end.

One of the actors looks like a young George Jones:

[image: George Jones]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   When and where did you see this?

Comment: [Species 2](https://youtu.be/26Y8rv9f0d8?t=40) ?

Comment: When you say "overtakes", do you mean "takes over"? They mean different things.

Comment: Possibly significant, does he kill his hosts? Leave them alive and bewildered when he switches bodies? Leaves just empty skin behind?

Comment: @ALEXANDER UHLIG  The word "overtake" means to travel in the same direction as someone who is ahead of you and travel faster and reach them and pass them.  It does not mean to possess someone.

Answer (score 13):

Could it be *The Hidden* (1987)? It stars Kyle MacLachlan and Michael Nouri. The description on Rotten Tomatoes is

> An FBI agent (Kyle MacLachlan) and a homicide detective (Michael Nouri) hunt the current human host of an orally exchanged alien life-form.

Young Kyle MacLachlan looks like the image you posted.
 [image: An image of Kyle MacLachlan as Lloyd Gallagher]

Comment: Interesting.  I thought of this one too, based on "FBI chasing a body-surfing alien" (we've had this answered before), but I thought that Kyle MacLachlan _didn't_ look like the picture of George Jones. :)  You should note that the ending doesn't match, though.

Comment: I haven't seen this movie in a few decades, so to be honest, I don't remember the ending at all. The only other movie I could think of was the one with John Goodman in it about the entity that move between bodies when they touched. But I can't remember the name of that one.

Comment: The one with John Goodman is [*Fallen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallen_(1998_film)) (1998) with Denzel Washington.